# How to hide menu items in dconf for all users?

Tags: linux, mate

I use **CentOS 7** with **"Mate desktop"** and I want to hide some menu items for all users (existing and new). For example, standard item **"System -> Preferences -> Hardware"**.

And second question: there is a **"Shutdown"** item in menu and I want to remove it too.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer for first question. It's resolve the problem in **mate-1.14**.

To set (hide) specifically items in **MATE menu** for all users you need to edit file

**/etc/xdg/menus/mate-preferences-categories.menu**

For example, you can simply remove strings:

```
<Menu>
 <Name>Hardware</Name>
 <Directory>mate-hardware.directory</Directory>
 <Include>
  <And>
    <Category>Settings</Category>
    <Category>HardwareSettings</Category>
    <Not><Category>System</Category></Not>
  </And>
 </Include>
</Menu>
```

If you want to remove link to "Control center" and item "Administration" then you can remove the desired sections in **/etc/xdg/menus/mate-settings.menu**.

It's some kind of dirty hack but it works :)